# Sentence construction with participles

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, participles

> A: A is drinking cups of coffee nonstop in the kitchen.
>
> B: What the hell! You trying to make your heart explode?
>
> A:  I am loading up on coffee. Because it is a pain in the ass
>   ***getting to the kitchen*** and I don't want to come back here.

I quoted this dialogue from an american sitcom.

This sentence's construction seems little different to me. I suppose "getting to the kitchen" refers to "it".

I think I can rewrite it as in sentence 2:

> 2- ...Because ***getting to the kitchen*** is a pain in the ass and I don't want to come back here.

Can I use sentence 3 too?

> 3-  ...Because it is a pain in the ass ***which is getting to the kitchen***
>   and I don't want to come back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exactly correct.

- "it" means "getting to the kitchen"
- It's exactly the same in meaning as "Because getting to the kitchen is a pain in the ass and I don't want to come back here."

Sentence 3 is ungrammatical.

Be aware: a) this is very informal: "You trying to make your heart explode?" instead of standard English: "Are you trying ...", b) you wouldn't use "Pain in the ass" or "what the hell" except in very informal circumstances, c) "ass" marks this as American English.

Comment: Thank you. Is this sentence- "...Because getting to the kitchen is a pain in the ass and I don't want to come back here." - more formal than the original one?

Comment: Not really: almost nothing with "ass" will be formal.  "Because getting to the X is irritating/difficult/boring/expensive/slow and I don't want to come back here."

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why speakers use original one instead of sentence 2? - "...Because getting to the kitchen is a pain in the ass and I don't want to come back here." - more formal than the original one? -  Because it is shorter and more direct than the original one.

Comment: It might help to think of these: "Because it's raining.  Because it's boring.  Because it's irritating.  Because it's fun.  Because it's illogical."  All are normal answers to why you do/don't want to do something.  You can find a thing to say is "it" (the weather, the action, the reason) but it probably better to learn them as "reason templates".

Comment: Lastly, can I use "to- infinitive" as well? -  "... Because it is a pain in the ass to get to the kitchen and I don't want to come back here.

Comment: Yes, however, if you're in the kitchen you'd probably say "getting to the kitchen", if you're somewhere else then "It's a pain to get to the kitchen and I don't want to go back there".  NB: can use "a pain in the neck" or just "a pain", which is acceptable everywhere.

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask one more thing if possible: Is "getting to the kitchen" a gerund or participle in this first sentence? (First sentence: Because it is a pain in the ass getting to the kitchen and I don't want to come back here.)

Comment: "getting" is a gerund here, acting as a noun.  "it" refers to the noun phrase "getting to the kitchen".  Here's a good explanation: http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participle.htm

Comment: Thanks. But they said: In this sentence, You did the right thing ***coming to me*** , coming to me was a participle. What is the functional difference between "getting to the kitchen" in the first sentence I asked and "coming to me" in the sentence above?

Comment: "coming to me" has an adverbial function on "did the right thing".  You can say "You did the right thing quickly", you can't say "*You did the right thing house".  But as **this is a an excellent question** I recommend you a post a new question about gerunds/participles with examples such as "Going to the house is irritating" and "You did the right thing going to the house".

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Can I use comma here: " Because it is a pain in the ass, getting to the kitchen and I don't want to come back here."